# XCode UITable Scrolling changing text values

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having a strange problem.

I load the values from online and display in my `UITableViewCell`. It is working fine... the problem I am facing is, if I scroll down the application fetches from online accordingly but when I scroll up, the value is matching correctly...

if `strLocation` is not null I am displaying the `LocationImageView`, if `strLocation` is null I am hiding `LocationImageView`. When I load the application initially this is working fine, when I scroll the table and move down, if some value has `strLocation` blank, it is hiding the `LocationImageView` but what happens, in the top of the table, where strLocation is not null, in those places also `LocationImageView` gets hidden.

I would like to know how to solve this issue

```
cell.cityLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"location"];

NSString *strLocation = [dictionary valueForKey:@"location"];


if ([strLocation isEqual:@""]){
    cell.LocationImageView.hidden=TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Post more code. In particular you should post your entire `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Its a big code, it will be confusing to understand the logic                       [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"HomeTablecell";
    
    cell = (HomeTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell.vEdit.hidden=TRUE;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HomeTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.allPostArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I had given partial code

Comment: It is impossible to say what is happening until we can be sure how you are dequeueing the cells. and please post it with your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard problem when dealing with cells. UITableView (if used properly) reuses cells so you need to update the cell correctly. If you allow that some component gets hidden you also need to place a code which will allow to show back that component if the data allows that. Looking at your snippet you are only hiding the component but there is no way to bing it back.

I guess looking at your code that doing this:

```
cell.LocationImageView.hidden=[strLocation isEqual:@""];
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: you are welcome, anyway I recommend you to review the UITableViewDelegate methods reference :) if you can please consider upvoting. All the best!